# Why is the output of my buffer is not printed?

Tags: c++

I wish you a happy new year =)

I have a behaviour I do not understand.

I try to fill a buffer with some data and when I print the buffer, nothing is print.

Here below my code :

```
uint8_t* buffer[50];
std::size_t pos = 0;
int cpt = 0;
while(pos < line.size())
{
   std::size_t index = line.find(str, pos);
   if(pos != std::string::npos)
   {
      string temp = line.substr(index,4);
      std::vector<uint8_t> myVector(temp.begin(), temp.end());
      uint8_t *p = &myVector[0];
      buffer[cpt] = (uint8_t*)p;
      std::cout << "Buffer[cpt] : " << buffer[cpt] << std::endl;
      cpt = cpt + 1;
    }
    pos = index + 4;
    std::cout << "buffer[0] : " << buffer[0] << std::endl;
}

for (int i=0; i < cpt; i++)
{
    std::cout << "Buffer : " <<  buffer[i] << std::endl;
}
```

The print of Buffer[cpt] is correct, I saw the last value I affect to the buffer
But the print of buffer[0] prints nothing
(Same behaviour into the print of the loop For)

Could someone knows why ?
And how could I get at the end of the loop while my buffer fills correctly ?

Thank you to all.

Comment: Not likely to be the problem here, but still worth mentioning: On any platform that have `uint8_t`, then it will be based on `char`. And any `char` based array or pointer will be treated as a null-terminated string. Is the pointers in `buffer` null-terminated strings?

Comment: And if you want to process string and have the results be strings, then use `std::string` *everywhere*. And if you don't know the final size of the `buffer` array, then use `std::vector`. So you should probably have `std::vector<std::string> buffer;`.

Comment: No, pointers in buffer is not null terminated.

Comment: Then you can't output the data using the standard `<<` operator. Since you get sub-strings from a longer string, then you really are dealing with strings, which leads to my previous comment about `std::string`. What is the purpose of using `uint8_t`? What is the data supposed to be used for? What is the underlying problem you try to solve with this code? If you tell us about the underlying and actual problem you need to solve (showing this code as part of your [mcve], as well as the input) then we might be able to help you better.

Comment: I'am using int8_t type because I made some test with a uint8_t buffer filled with hard code values (values are hex values) then send this buffer via a TCP socket and it works. Now, I would like do the same thing, but I would like to read a file with my hex value inside (0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04 for example) then add all of them in a buffer to send it. To be honest, I do not know if there is a more simple way to do that.

Comment: When you say "hex values", do you mean a *string* with hexadecimal values as in `"0x01 0x02"` etc.? Or is the string initialized with the raw binary value `1` and `2` etc.? Because if it's an actual string then the string `"0x01"` will not be that easily converted to the integer `1` (`0x01`).

Comment: Yes when I open the file, it is 0x01, 0x02 which are wrote inside the file. I trying another way with a char buffer[], it seems more simple...

Answer (score 2):

You are saving the address of the data for a vector that is then destructed. This leads to undefined behavior when you call to print `buffer[0]` and `buffer[i]` later.

If you're using vectors to begin with, why do you need the raw `uint8_t*` array?

```
{
  string temp = line.substr(index,4);
  std::vector<uint8_t> myVector(temp.begin(), temp.end());
  uint8_t *p = &myVector[0];
  buffer[cpt] = (uint8_t*)p;
  std::cout << "Buffer[cpt] : " << buffer[cpt] << std::endl;
  cpt = cpt + 1;
} // myVector is destructed here

pos = index + 4;
std::cout << "buffer[0] : " << buffer[0] << std::endl; 
// buffer[0] points to memory allocated by 
// myVector that has now been released, undefined behavor.
```

Comment: Because I read a file and I parse the file to put datas in the buffer. And I need to use uint8_t type for the buffer